# MYSQL - Displaying rows with max count values in a group with other columns

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count, max

I have been searching at lot and have found topics like similar topics but none were exactly the solutions that I was looking for. In this case, I have a working code, but something that seems extremely hacky to me and should have a simpler and better way of getting it done.

**The "Test" table**

```
id
--
 1
 1
 1
 2
 2
 2
 3
 4
 4
```

Nothing complex, just a simple table with some repeating `id` values

What I want is to group these `id` together and show all the `id` that are repeating the most i.e

```
id | count
----------
 1       3
 2       3
```

**The solution that I have currently come up with**

```
select
    @max := max(count) as count
from (
    select 
        id,
        count(id) as count
    from 
        test
    group by
        id
)
as 
    inner_table;


select
    id, count
from (
    select 
        id,
        count(id) as count
    from 
        test
    group by
        id
)
as 
    inner_table
where count = @max;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do it with `group by` and `having`.

```
select id,count(*) as cnt
from t
group by id
having count(*)=(select count(*) as cnt 
                 from t 
                 group by id
                 order by cnt desc
                 limit 1)
```